# How to count signals within a trend - or mark the first sig after trend changes

Tags: tradingview-api

I would need the counter to reset, (say) from a bear flag to a bull flag, when trend indicator is crossed.

I searched Tradingview documentation and among working scripts and found no examples of a resetting counter, or a way to mark only the first signal in many signals of a series.

I used to do this in Java by separate procedures for bull and bear counting where each would zero out the other. Signal test was then if (say) bull counter just turned to '1' and prior bull count was '0'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your trend counter variables with the `var` keyword, this allows you to save a value in those variables that you can reset whenever the trend changes.

Here is an example script that will count the number of candles within each trend. Whenever the closing price of a candle crosses the EMA, the trend is considered changed, and the candle counter variable is reset.

```js
//@version=5
indicator("trendCounter", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

float ema = ta.ema(close, 50)

var int bullCounter = 0
var int bearCounter = 0

if barstate.isconfirmed and ta.cross(close, ema)
    if (close > ema)
        label.new(bar_index, low, str.format("Bull Trend Started\nThere were {0} candles\nduring the bear trend", bearCounter), color = color.green, textcolor = color.white)
        bearCounter := 0
        
    else
        label.new(bar_index, low, str.format("Bear Trend Started\nThere were {0} candles\nduring the bull trend", bullCounter), color = color.red, textcolor = color.white)
        bullCounter := 0

if barstate.isconfirmed and close > ema
    bullCounter += 1
else if barstate.isconfirmed and close < ema
    bearCounter += 1

// Plots
plot(ema, "EMA", color.white)

// Debug
plot(bullCounter, "bullCounter", display = display.data_window)
plot(bearCounter, "bearCounter", display = display.data_window)
```

[image: trendCounter script screenshot]